# Grouping carpool participant addresses for network

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, network-analyst, grouping

I have a list of addresses of people participating in carpools to a workplace and a list of cars given by the workplace. Both lists change daily.

I need to group people by their addresses and assign them cars by the group size (and then calculate their route to work, but that's the easy part).

How can I group points (worker addresses) by their geographic location, or better yet, by their closeness on the road network?

I'm using ArcInfo 10.1. I tried using the Grouping Analysis (which groups by geographic location and distance from the workplace), but it's giving me weird results.

Comment: Can you expand a little bit on the "weird" results -- not what you expected? completely wrong? groups too large? etc. :)

Comment: Not what I expected. Not completely wrong, but some of the grouping grouped people living very far from each other (and not only the "leftovers" but it happened a few times). Also, The grouping does not consider "network distances" which can be crucial for carpool planning.

Comment: It may be the case that "weird results" are unavoidable, and some level of human oversight is necessary. Eg if there are 6 people in a town, and the only car available fits 5 people, 1 person will be left out - no matter how smart your algorithm

Comment: @Stephan Lead, by weird I didn't mean the situation you described, but more like making 2 groups of 5, in both 4 are close together and the fifth is a lot closer to the 4 points of the other group.

Comment: Only the Network Analyst extension is required to solve these kinds of problems.  Use Solve Vehicle Routing Problem for a geoprocessing service and Make Vehicle Routing Problem Layer tool for doing Desktop Analysis.  Both create multiple routes to optimize the use of a fleet of vehicles.  The extension is not free.

Comment: This link explains the Make Vehicle Routing Problem Layer http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00470000004v000000  The problems are described in terms of a commercial fleet, but the restaurant grease pick up problem is similar to what you are trying to do, except with people instead of grease.

Comment: The main challenge is how to match between people to share a ride, and to decide who picks up whom with their vehicle, so that it will be worthwhile both for the driver and all the passengers. Even if we assume that every driver can pick up at most one other passenger, the problem is challenging.

Comment: maybe buffer the drivers route and check if the passenger is in the buffer

Comment: Geog, The driver is the Farthest living person in the group and the group is determined daily, so your suggestions aren't good, but thanks.

Comment: If not mistaken, Grouping algorithm doesn't consider the size of the group. As @RichardFairhurst mentioned you should use Vehicle Routing Problem which requires street network.

Comment: There has been quite a lot of advice offered and clarifications sought/given as comments.  To try and progress this I think you should edit your question to revise it into a clearer question.